# C# HttpWebRequest with XML Structured Data

Tags: c#

I'm developing the client-side of a third party webservice. The purpose is that I send xml-file to the server.
How should I attach the xml-file to the httpwebrequest? What contentType is needed? More suggestions?

I cannot use mtom or dime.ie because I am using httpwebrequest. I am unable to use WCF either.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Here is a very basic method of sending XML structured data using HttpWebRequest (by the way you need to use request.ContentType = "application/xml";) :

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(myUrl));
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/xml";
request.Accept = "application/xml";

XElement redmineRequestXML =
    new XElement("issue",
    new XElement("project_id", 17)
);

byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(redmineRequestXML.ToString());

request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;

using (Stream putStream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    putStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
}

// Log the response from Redmine RESTful service
using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
{
    Logger.Info("Response from Redmine Issue Tracker: " + reader.ReadToEnd());
}
```

I use this at one of my projects ([NBug](http://www.nbusy.com/projects/nbug)) to submit an issue report to my Redmine issue tracker which accepts XML structured data over web requests (via POST). If you need further examples, you can get a couple of fully featured examples here: http://nbug.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets (click 'Browse' under 'Latest Verion' label on the right then navigate to "NBug\Submit\Tracker\Redmine.cs")

Comment: HttpWebRequest is a derived class from WebRequest.  How is it that you can cast a WebRequest to a HttpWebRequest?