# unable to read values from Request.Params in c#

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, saml, saml-2.0

I have following piece of code which is troubling me to read the value from `Request.Params`. Right now I just want to read values (in receiver) that I'm passing from sender i.e. username and SAMLResponse.

**Sender**

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpWebRequest httpWReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("MY URL");
    httpWReq.Method = "Post";
    XElement obj = XElement.Load(@"Load.xml");
    StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder();
    postData = postData.Append("username=user&SAMLResponse=").Append(obj.ToString());                

    byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData.ToString());

    httpWReq.Method = "POST";
    httpWReq.ContentType = "text/xml;encoding='utf-8'";
    httpWReq.ContentLength = data.Length;

    using (Stream stream = httpWReq.GetRequestStream())
    {
        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    }

    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)httpWReq.GetResponse();

    string responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
}
```

**Receiver**

```
public ActionResult LoginSSO()
{
    string rawSamlData, WindowName;
    SSOModel objSSOModel = new SSOModel();
    string str = Request.Params["username"];
    str = Request.Params["SAMLResponse"];
    ...
    ..
}
```

**Error**:

[image]

Any idea, what is going wrong?

Comment: `string str = Request.Querystring["username"];`

Answer (score 0):

Can you change this line:

```
httpWReq.ContentType = "text/xml;encoding='utf-8'";
```

to this:

```
httpWReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
```

And give us a result?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I tried that before, and it didn't work. Result remain the same. Hence I'm also posting XML content, then I switched to what you're suggesting.. But no luck

Comment: Then try `application/xml` instead of `text/xml`

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5653743/c-sharp-httpwebrequest-with-xml-structured-data

Answer (score 0):

I see a few issues with your code.

1. Encoding - you should encode the XML file when you do `obj.ToString()` as it may contain characters that will confuse things.
2. content type - You are telling the receiver that you are sending XML but you are really sending a form. So you should set the content type to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: I'm encoding `postData` as whole. And for content type, I tried that before, but it didn't work. Then I switched to what I have now.

Comment: You may need to [`HttpUtility.UrlEncode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4fkewx0t.aspx) your post data before writing it to the stream.

Answer (score 0):

This works in my application.

1. As other answerers said, changed content-type to `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` in **Sender**.
2. Changed `string str = Request.Params["username"];` to `string str = Request.Form["username"];` or `string str = Request["username"];` in **Receiver**.

I hope they will work in your application as well.

Comment: Did you try with XML content?

Comment: @AmneshGoel No, because this worked for me. Didn't this work for you?

Comment: I had to pass XML content.. what is point in testing with normal content?

Comment: If you are getting `System.Web.HttpRequestValidationException` at `str = Request.Params["SAMLResponse"];`, try `Request.Unvalidated.Form["SAMLResponse"]` in addition to the above.