# Unable to post SAML response to a valid receiver

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, saml, saml-2.0

I'm trying to post one `SAML Response` to a valid URL (MVC). I can hit the URL, but system is not able to read the `SAML Response`. Following is the piece of code that may help you to help me.

SAML Response

[image]

Posting this SAML Response with following code.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpWebRequest httpWReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("LOGIN SSO URL HERE");

    XElement obj = XElement.Load(@"SAMLResponse.xml");
    StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder();

    postData = postData.Append(obj.ToString());            

    byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData.ToString());

    httpWReq.Method = "POST";
    httpWReq.ContentType = "text/xml;encoding='utf-8'";
    httpWReq.ContentLength = data.Length;

    using (Stream stream = httpWReq.GetRequestStream())
    {
        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    }

    ....

}
```

Following is the Response object that I'm getting in MVC.

[image]

Finally I'm getting error as

> Unable to find SAMLResponse

Comment: How is this question any different than the [one you posted 20 minutes ago](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33120879/unable-to-read-values-from-request-params-in-c-sharp)?

Comment: This is specific to posting SAML Response. Read it again pls. Plus this has SAML response that I'm trying to post. Both are different questions.